# Hidden features/tricks of Flash development, Flash language (AS2/3), and Flash IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, ide

Guys, I am thoroughly surprised that there is no Flash *Hidden Features* post yet in the [Hidden Features series](http://beerpla.net/2009/06/21/hidden-features-of-perl-php-javascript-c-c-c-java-ruby-python-and-others-collection-of-incredibly-useful-lists/) that I've been tracking for a while now.

There is a recent [AS3/Flex one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103705/hidden-features-of-actionscript3-flex) but it's not very active and I don't exactly mean just AS3 when I say Flash here.

The Hidden Features series is great for people who are new to a certain language. It shows the ropes and certain valuable tricks, all in one place. I think it's a brilliant idea. Even experts sometimes find tricks they'd never heard about.

When I started with Flash, I was taken aback by the Flash IDE and odd concepts of Flash, compared to other programming languages.

So, here goes: what are some **hidden features** of **Flash** as a **language (AS2/3)** and the **Flash IDE**?

Let the fun begin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Flash IDE]

This isn't a feature as much as it is a gotcha. When specifying a document class for an FLA, the compiler does not subclass that class, it *modifies* it.

This can cause problems when you have several SWFs with the same document class, all being loaded into another SWF (since two classes with the same name cannot be loaded side-by-side into the same application domain). It results in the first being loaded and the second using the first's modified class, producing weird errors (as you can imagine).

The solution is either:

- Create a proxy class for each FLA that subclasses the document class
- Load each SWF into a new child application domain

Comment: oh.. I see this is the correct answer! 8P

Answer (score 11):

[AS3] Tips for working with arrays or Vectors

Fastest way through an array, always from the back

```
var i:int = array.length;
var item:Object;
while(i--)
{
   item = array[i];
}
```

Clearing an array,

```
//faster than array = []
array.length = 0;

//garbage friendly
while(array.length)
{
    array.pop();
}
```

Pushing and splicing

```
//faster than array.push();
array[array.length] = "pushed value";

//faster than splice(index, 1)
var index:int = array.indexOf(splicee);
array[index] = null;
array.splice(array.length, 1);
```

Cloning

```
//fastest way to clone
var newArray:Array = array.concat();

//fastest manipulation
var mapFunction:Function = function(item:Object, index:int, source:Array):Object
{
    return //your cloning or morphing here
}
var newArray:Array = array.map(mapFunction);
```

Comment: How does the Pushing and splicing example work? Aren't you splicing from past the end of the array?

Answer (score 8):

**MovieClip.addFrameScript()** is a undocumented ActionScript 3.0 feature that allows you to specify a function that is called when the playhead of the Movieclip timeline enters a particular frame number.

```
function someFunction():void {

}

movieclip_mc.addFrameScript(4,someFunction);
```

The frame number is zero based (1st frame = 0) and needs to be whole numbers only, however if you wanted to use *frame labels* you could use something like this:

```
function addFrameLabelScript(frame:String, func:Function):void{
    var labels:Array = currentLabels;
    for(var i:int=0;i<labels.length;i++){
        if(labels[i].name == frame){
            addFrameScript(labels[i].frame-1,func);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very useful hidden function there, before I have been using an `ENTER_FRAME` event and checking to see if the new `currentFrame` value is n. this is much more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

```
Graphics::drawRoundRectComplex (x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number, topLeftRadius:Number, topRightRadius:Number, bottomLeftRadius:Number, bottomRightRadius:Number) : void;
```

It's not documented anywhere, but a [forum post explains more](http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/actionscript/flash-cs3-drawroundrectcomplex-88680.html).

Comment: Can you document it here then?

Answer (score 4):

[AS3]

The `||` (logical or) operator can be used for any truthy/falsey values.

```
var obj : Object = nullObject || instance; // instance
var val : int = 5 || 10; // 5
var val : int = 0 || 10; // 10
```

Also, you can use `&` and `|` (bitwise and/or) to do a non-short-circuted expression:

```
function functionA() { return false; }
function functionB() { return true; }

if (functionA() && functionB()) { trace("something"); } // methodB won't be executed
if (functionA() & functionB()) { trace("something"); } // methodB WILL be executed
```

Answer (score 3):

[AS3]

When you use the trace statement in AS3 you can pass in multiple parameters and AS3 will format the output so that there is a space between each.

```
trace("Hello","World");
```

would output "Hello World".

AS2 does not support multiple parameters for trace so you are forced to do something like

```
trace("Hello "+"World");
```

Answer (score 3):

[AS3]

```
var list : Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
```

becomes slightly shorter by writing

```
var list : Vector.<Object> = new <Object>[];
```

You can even predefine values:

```
var list : Vector.<Object> = new <Object>["one", "two", "three"];
```

Answer (score 2):

### ActionScript 2

every class is a function and every function a class ... AS2 is prototype based ...

```
trace.prototype = { };
var f = trace;
trace(new f());//will yield [object Object]
```

accessing `Function::prototype` allows extending classes at runtime:

```
MovieClip.prototype.moo = function () {
    trace(this+" says 'moooooooo' ...");
}
_root.moo();//_level0 says 'moooooooo' ...
```

---

`Object::__proto__` ... allows you to change the prototype of an object, which can be used for runtime reclassing:

```
var o = trace;
o.__proto__ = [];
trace(o.push("foo", "bar", "foobar"));//3 here
trace(o.length);//also 3
trace(o[1]);//bar
```

in this example, the function `trace` is reclassed to Array ... pretty cool, huh? :)

---

`Function::apply` and `Function::call` allow applying **any** function as a method to **any** object:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(trace,[1,2,3]);
trace(trace.length);//3
trace(Array.prototype.splice.call(trace, 1,1));//2 ... actually, this is [2] (the array containing 2)
```

---

using the three above, instantiation of a class `MyClass` with parameters `param_1, ..., param_n` can be written as:

```
var instance = {};
instance.__proto__ = MyClass.prototype;
MyClass.call(instance, param_1, ..., param_n);
```

---

a corelation of `Function::push` and `Function::apply` is that `this` is simply a function argument, that is passed automatically ... as any other function argument, it can be written to ...

```
var f:Function = function () {
    this = [];
    this.push(1,2,3);
    trace(this);//1,2,3
    this = _root;
    trace(this);//_level0
}
f();
```

`Object::__resolve` ... settings this method allows you to react to lookups on undefined properties ... this is fun and useful for proxying, mocking, composition, delegation, and so on ...

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;

var jack:Carpenter = ...
var jim:BlackSmith = ...
...
var guys:Array = [jack, jim, ...]
var o = { __resolve : function (name:String) {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < guys.length; i++) {
        var guy = guys[i];
        if (guy.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            var ret = guy[name];
            if (ret instanceof Function) {
                ret = Delegate.create(guy, return);
            }
            return return;
        }
    }
    return "sorry man, but nobody knows, what '" + name + "' means";
});

//some really imaginary stuff (i hope it makes the point):
trace(o.saw);//[object Hammer]
trace(o.anvil);//[object Anvil]
trace(o.ventilator);//"sorry man, but nobody knows, what 'ventilator' means"
trace(o.makeSword());//[object Sword]
```

---

that's it for now ... there's an awfull lot more ... the thing is simply, that AS2 is an exiting language, but painfully slow ... AS3 in comparison is boring as hell, but the speed increase is really great ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 2):

[AS3]

When looking for a the value of a variable, the player will run up the scope chain until it finds what it's looking for.  So using nested (anonymous) functions you do things like make asynchronous calls and handle it using variables that were defined on the scope of the calling method. e.g.

```
function loadData(myAwesomeObject : AwesomeObject) : void
{

   var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event : Event) : void
   {
      myAwesomeObject.someReallyAwesomeMethod(event.target);
   });
   urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://someService"));

}
```

Loads of other uses for this and it's really very useful

Comment: Anonymous functions will screw up debugging since they are not part of a helpful scope chain. Plus, they are really hard to read and make maintenance a chore.

Comment: They most certainly do not screw up debugging. You can step through an anonymous function no problem.  Plus the addition of an extra scope level when used properly is a helpful construct. So long as they are succinct in their contents they are not hard to read. Granted a hundred line anonymous function is wrong. 5-10 lines of code is perfectly readable and mainatinable.

Comment: @Tim B - I'm far from Adobe's biggest fan, but your misunderstanding of closures hardly equates to them "screwing up" debugging.

Comment: After 2 years of supporting an application rife with anonymous functions, I disagree with these 2 responses. When the debugger/logger spits out <anonymous> in the scope chain, I have no clue where the failure is. I consider that a "screw up", as in "the developer screwed up my life with his shortcut."
To me, anonymous functions create more headaches than solutions. My opinion is based on experience, not misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tim B - The method stack always contains the method from which the anonymous method was called and can be navigated to in within the FB debugger. I don't doubt that you've seen misuse of closures, but any feature can be misused.

Comment: @Tim B - Used properly the extra scope is a tool not a 'shortcut'. When it's used for the purpose it was designed for it's extremely powerful.  Like Richard Szalay said all programing constructs can be misused... looks like you got the raw end of the deal in having to maintain badly written code!

Comment: Fair enough, I have developed a deep mistrust of this kind of coding approach and avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [weak references in ActionScript3](http://www.bigroom.co.uk/blog/create-your-own-weak-references-in-actionscript-3) by using the Dictionary object.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you using FlashDevelop, there is some nifty conditional compilation functionality:

```
// Use it to generate different code paths
CONFIG::debug {
   txt.text = "Debug Version running...";
}
CONFIG::release {
    txt.text = "Welcome to Stark Industries";
}

// Or use it as a const in code
if ( CONFIG::debug && yourCondition ) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

read more about it [here](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation)

Comment: Is there a way to use these configuration-dependent constants in the Pre-Build Command Line?  I would like to do something like if(CONIFG::debug) { nant debug } else { nant }

Comment: Conditional compile is available in other IDE too. Tried it in IntellijIdea.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really hidden (very obscured in the documentation), but [updateAfterEvent](http://help.adobe.com/es_ES/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/TimerEvent.html#updateAfterEvent%28%29) is quite an unknown and useful method under certain circumstances...

Answer (score 1):

[AS3]

I wouldn't necessarily call this a 'feature', but you can actually access variables before they are defined (even with strict compilation) due to the way the compiler works:

```
trace(hb); // null
var hb : HBox = new HBox;
trace(hb); // [object]
```

It can actually lead to frustration when refactoring code (since it compiles).

Comment: I read somewhere that this is because when a function runs, it will run through the entire function once first and declare every local variable. Only after that will it start execution of the function.

Comment: @EyeSeeEm - Very likely true for AS2, but in AS3 it's simply the way it's compiled.

Comment: After AVM2 (AS3) swf is decompiled back from bytecode, it has all local vars in functions defined in the very beginning. So it is the way the compiler works)

Answer (score 1):

[Flash IDE]

When you export a MovieClip as a swc you can add it to the components panel of by dropping it into the folder

C:\Documents and Settings\USER_NAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Adobe\Flash CS3\en\Configuration\Components\SOME_COMPONENT_FOLDER

Restart flash and it'll be in the components panel for you to use.

Comment: Vista/7 don't call it "Documents and Settings". %userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Adobe\Flash CS3\en\Configuration\Components\SOME_COMPONENT_FOLDER will work for all versions.

Answer (score 1):

Well this might not be a hidden feature but maybe people have missed that there are external tweening engines you can use. My latest favourite is Greensocks.
The only thing in my opinion it has lacked seems to be improving, workflow. 
Have not tested v.11 yet but definitely will on my next AS project:
http://blog.greensock.com/v11beta/

Comment: You can't touch tweenlite, I'm just a little concerned about the license. Tweensy is also very good/fast.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly hidden, but what about the often overlooked "include" macro (yes, it still exists in as3)? - very useful for faking multiple inheritance (when used side by side with an interface), even if it usually is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

when using flashvars write a utility method getFlashVars().

```
function getFlashVars():Object {
return Object(LoaderInfo(this.loaderInfo).parameters);
```

}

then when I'm coding I always add an extra || so that I won't have to flashvars while debugging.

```
localVar = getFlashVars().sampleVar || "default.xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

[as3]

prototype based inheritance :

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var myRectangle = function(target,x,y){
    var internalTarget = target;
    var myMovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var myGraphic = myMovieClip.graphics;
    myGraphic.beginFill(0xAAAAAA);
    myGraphic.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    myGraphic.endFill();
    trace(typeof internalTarget);
    Sprite(internalTarget).addChild(myMovieClip);
    myMovieClip.x = x ;
    myMovieClip.y = y ;
}
var aRectangle = new myRectangle(this,10,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something most people don't know: MouseEvents are tracked outside of the application window if the MOUSE_DOWN event has been fired, but not MOUSE_UP. You can grab mouse positions outside of the application window (and even outside of the browser window) **as long as whatever you're doing makes the user hold their mouse down.** To test this, try running the following code:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function init():void {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, magic)
        }

        protected function magic(e:Event):void {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moreMagic);
        }

        protected function moreMagic(e:MouseEvent):void {
            magicalButton.label = "Hold me down! " + String(e.stageX) + "x" + String(e.stageY);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>    
<s:Button id="magicalButton" label="Hold me down!"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This package will get you all the DisplayObjects in DisplayObjectContainer by setting class types.

Note: It wont count frames in MovieClips.

```
package {

import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

/**
 * 
 * @author Cansın Şenalioğly @ cansin.senalioglu@gmail.com
 *   
 */ 

//--------------------------------------
//  Class description
//--------------------------------------
/**
 * <p>Gets all DisplayObject types in DisplayObjectContainer.</p>
 *
 * @langversion 3.0
 * @playerversion Flash 9.0.28.0
 * @includeExample examples/ButtonExample.as
 *  
 *  @playerversion AIR 1.0
 */

public class DisplayObjectFinder
{

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * <p>Gets all DisplayObject type in DisplayObjectContainer</p>
     * <b>Example:</b><br> 
     * <p>var items:Array = DisplayObjectFinder.getAllDOTypeInDOC(stage,MovieClip,callBack);<br>
     * trace(items.length);<br>
     * function callBack(object:MovieClip):void{ trace(object.name) };</p>
     *
     * @param container Objects parent (DisplayObjectCotainer);
     * @param typeClass Objects Class type;
     * @param forEach For every object call back function;
     * 
     * @langversion 3.0
     * @playerversion Flash 9.0.28.0
     *  
     *  @playerversion AIR 1.0
     */ 
    public static function getAllDOTypeInDOC(container:DisplayObjectContainer,typeClass:Class,forEach:Function=null):Array {
        var a:Array = [];
        var len:int = container.numChildren;
        while(len--){
            var o:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(len);
            if(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(o) == flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(typeClass)){
                a[a.length] = o;
                if(forEach != null)
                    forEach(o);
            }
            if(o is DisplayObjectContainer){
                var aa:Array = getAllDOTypeInDOC(o as DisplayObjectContainer,typeClass,forEach);
                var lena:int = aa.length;
                while(lena--){
                    a[a.length] = aa[lena];
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flash Professional, you can change a MovieClip symbol to a Sprite by redirecting it's base class from `flash.display.MovieClip` to `flash.display.Sprite`, and the symbol icon color in the library will change from blue to green.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom metadata isn't something that's well documented or promoted, but it's very helpful - without modifying a variable or changing its namespace, you can give it custom annotations similar to the way that you can in Java.

It is gone over in depth by Christophe Conraets on [his blog](http://coenraets.org/blog/2007/10/annotating-actionscript-classes-with-custom-metadata-simple-orm-framework-for-air/).

The simplicity of it is that you can put all of your own metadata, and then you just use `describeType()` and you will see all of your custom metadata at run time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another gotcha:

By default Flash tools strips any metadata tags that you have.  Many frameworks depends on these metadata tags.  What you need to be careful is that this doesn't only apply to the compiler, but also to the optimizer.  Be sure to run both your compiler and optimizer with -keep-as3-metadata-tag option to keep your metadata tag in there.