# Undocumented AS3 API

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Recently, I happen to know MovieClip.addFrameScript() which is very useful, otherwise timeline script should be coded in fla. Do you know any other undocumented Actionscript3 API?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160680/hidden-features-tricks-of-flash-development-flash-language-as2-3-and-flash-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one:

It allows you to specify a function that is called when the playhead of the Movieclip timeline enters the specified frame number.

Their are four parameters to the method.

```
MovieClip.addFrameScript(frame:uint, notify:Function, ?:bool, ?:bool)
```

Passing false as the third parameter and anything as the fourth parameter, clears the function, so that it is no longer called when the playhead enters a previously defined frame number/function combo.

Comment: I didn't realize it can have 3rd, 4th parameter. Thanks.