# Actionscript tricks

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

There is so many ways to improve the actionscript performance and reduce code size. Let share what tricks you can come up with.

Comment: I voted to close; as the question is not direct.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be closed, just edited so its more specific. However if its going to be this broad, then it should be closed.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1160680/78782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search on google for as3 tips you can find a lot. First check all the pages on the kirupa forum.
[Kirupa tricks and tips](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=223798)

Grant Skinner also made some nice performace tips and tricks about the Flash 10(.1)

Then if you want to profile self and see some deep going optimization's go visit [jpaucliar's blog](http://jpauclair.net/)